# How to capture a full website screenshot with C# and WebKit.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, webkit, screenshot

I am using [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) to integrate a browser component in my C# application. The problem is I can only capture the visible part in the browser window with a screenshot. Is there a way to capture the screenshot of the whole page?

Comment: @EmanueleGreco No unfortunately not, but I will have a look tomorrow if I can extract a minimal version of it for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I think I will go with the awesomium solution since it provides the intermediate layer for injecting JavaScript code also, which is really convenient for my future plans.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems that it is kind of possible by using NativeMethods.SendMessage, although this can screw up the message queue, could you use http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/ or perhaps http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/ or http://labs.awesomium.com/capturing-web-pages-with-c-net/?

Answer (score 7):

I use WebBrowser instead; `ScrollBarsEnabled = false` let me capture whole page.

Here is some code:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
 {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(builder));
        base.Render(htw);
        string html = builder.ToString();

        _Generate(html);
 } 


private void _Generate(string html)
{
    var browser = new WebBrowser { ScrollBarsEnabled = false };
    DisplayHtml(html, browser);
    browser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
    while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
       Application.DoEvents();  
    browser.Dispose();
}

private void DisplayHtml(string html, WebBrowser browser)
{
    browser.Navigate("about:blank");
    if (browser.Document != null)
    {
        browser.Document.Write(string.Empty);
    }
    browser.DocumentText = html;
}
```

Comment: I have stumbled several solutions using the WebBrowser component, but I am interested in using the WebKit engine for capturing it.

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    public byte[] picbytes;

    private void capture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        makepicture(txtURL.Text.Trim());
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        pictureBox1.Image = ByteToImage(picbytes);
    }

    private void makepicture(string url)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
            {
                browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                browser.AllowNavigation = true;
                browser.Navigate(url);
                browser.Width = 1024;
                browser.Height = 1575;
                browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DocumentCompleted);
                while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                }

            }
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }

    private void DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(browser.Width, browser.Height))
        {
            browser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, browser.Width, browser.Height));
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
                picbytes = bytes;

            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
    {
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] pData = blob;
        mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream, false);
        mStream.Dispose();
        return bm;

    }
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code? ('Edit', select everything, Ctrl-k). Thanks.

Comment: This works perfectly, with one flaw..  You really need to know the dimensions to set the browser control, because it will only print what's within.  I guess it's now a search to find, how to tell how wide and how high a web page is.

Comment: within DocumentCompleted() add the following, right after creating the browser object.

int height = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
int width = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;

browser.Height = height;
browser.Width = width;