# Capture Screenshot of entire Scrolling Webpage using C#

Tags: c#, capture, webpage-screenshot

I need to Capture Screenshot of entire Scrolling Webpage using C#.By entire Webpage I mean even the non-visible parts of the webpage visible on scrolling down. I can capture Screenshot of a new URL/Browser using Windows Form's WebBrowser but I want to capture from an existing Browser. 
I've Tried http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10763/Image-Capture-Whole-Web-Page-using-C
but without much effect. Please help.

P.S. I am a novice in .Net, please bear with me ..

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does not Work? The Code from CodeProject looks clear and suitable for me. Post some Code!

Comment: Search helps
- http://stackoverflow.com/a/2496277/1611349  
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048213/how-to-capture-a-full-website-screenshot-with-c-sharp-and-webkit-net   
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316564/taking-screenshot-of-a-webpage-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/Capture-screenshot-of-website-in-c-sharp.html.

Using the DLL provided by websitescreenshot team,you can create the webpage image. The only thing is they open the webpage in IE engine. So if your page will not open in IE, you won't get the image correctly.