# Webkit showing Blank Page

Tags: c#, browser, webkit

I am currently using WebKit in C# .net.
I am facing trouble while loading this page in WEBKIT.
http://shop.orange.co.uk/mobile-phones/4g-ready-phones or http://www.vax.co.uk/
WEBKIT showing other web pages content successfully
but in case of the above web page. there is
a blank web page. there is not Page original Content.
while this page is working fine in Firefox, Opera browsers.
any help regarding this ?
Infect this is not the only page.
regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found no way to inspect or debug html/javascript with webkitdotnet project. And it seems it's not maintained a while.

So if you have ability to move to other web engines, I would recommend [CefSharp - Embedded Chromium for .NET](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp). It's powerful engine that, I believe, has all capabilities webkitdotnet has, and also it allows to attach Chrome browser inspector to debug the page. To do this, you need to set RemoteDebuggingPort property:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088;

Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Then you can open url `http://localhost:8088` in your Chrome browser to attach embedded engine that runs in your app.

CefSharp project's sources contain examples of both WinForms and WPF applications. You can start easily with this examples.

**UPDATE:** In the moment of writing CefSharp component doesn't support taking full page snapshots as an image. I created ChromiumWebBrowserWithSnapshotSupport class in a forked branch https://github.com/ivan-sam/CefSharp . I've modified CefSharp.Wpf.Example project and added Snapshot button that makes snapshot of the page and opens an image. You also can put this control on WinForms form using [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you can't move, the only available option I see is to download affected page locally with all related content (scripts, css and so on), and host it with local web server. Then modify it to use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) as described in this article (http://habrahabr.ru/post/154917/ - it's in Russian):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...

    <script type='text/javascript' src='/path/to/firebug-lite.js'>
    {
        overrideConsole: true,
        startInNewWindow: true,
        startOpened: true,
        enableTrace: true
    }
    </script>

    ...
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

and to allow Firebug to be open in a new window you should add the following C# code:

```
browser.Url = new Uri(
    "http://localhost/path/to/debug-version-of-interface.html",
    System.UriKind.Absolute);

browser.NewWindowCreated += new NewWindowCreatedEventHandler(
(sender, newWindowEventArgs) =>
{
    // create new form with single item - Firebug Lite window
    debuggerForm = new DebuggerForm(newWindowEventArgs.WebKitBrowser);
    debuggerForm.Show();
});
```

Firebug lite gives you access to HTML DOM of the page and JavaScript console.

Happy debugging ^)

Comment: it is another webpage not which is not working..
www.vax.co.uk

Comment: i suspect the earlier webpage themes is changed by web master and shows result in webkitbrowsertest.exe while
www.vax.co.uk is the website to understand the problem.

Comment: it seems cef sharp doesnot generate image from webpage..
I want to generate snapshot of the webpage with cefsharp.

Comment: What kind of snapshot do you need? If it's visible to user part of the page, i.e. viewport (exactly what you see in the control) you can use DrawToBitmap method (see an example here http://maxivak.com/taking-screenshots-of-websites-with-net-windows-forms/). Example refers GeckoWebBrowser but works with CefSharp in the same way. If you meant snapshot of the whole page (non visible parts too), please provide code sample how you achieved this with WebKitDonNet (I found only this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048213/how-to-capture-a-full-website-screenshot-with-c-sharp-and-webkit-net).

Comment: tagRECT frameBounds = ((webFrameClass)((IWebView)wb.GetWebView()).mainFrame()).contentBounds();
                int frameWidth = frameBounds.right - frameBounds.left;
                int frameHeight = frameBounds.bottom - frameBounds.top;
                //wb.Size = new Size(frameWidth, frameHeight );
                wb.Size = new Size(frameWidth, (int)(frameHeight * 1.01)); 
 wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
//where wb is webkit.net browser

Comment: i need completed webpage as image.. or snapshot of webpage not the browser or control.

Comment: Haven't found trivial solution too. I'll try to implement it in my free time.

Comment: I've implemented snapshot feature in a fork branch and updated the answer. Please see update and try it.