# Capturing Full web page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Want to take full web page screen shot. i have tried below code but it is taking only visible portion. i want to take full web page screenshot that is visible and invisible

here is my code

```
 protected void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Capture("C:/Users/MintFDI/Downloads/ScreenShot.Jpeg");

}

  public static void Capture(String CapturedFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as System.Drawing.Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(10, 65, 20, 25, bitmap.Size);
        bitmap.Save(CapturedFilePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981670/programmatically-get-a-screenshot-of-a-page, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048213/how-to-capture-a-full-website-screenshot-with-c-sharp-and-webkit-net#13048302

Comment: i have gone through  all these solutions, but none is working. please help me out with my stuff

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ScreenShot Gist](https://gist.github.com/JoshClose/1366260) from Josh Close or the [Webpage thumbnailer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15211/Webpage-thumbnailer) from dooskoobi on CodeProject.